# AWS Lambda to RDS (Postgres) inside same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have the following setup in AWS:

```
API Gateway -> Lambda -> RDS (postgres)
```

My Lambda and RDS instance are inside the same VPC with Security Groups configured that allow all traffic Inbound and Outbound.

When I trigger my Lambda via API Gateway, the following is shown in the CloudWatch logs:

```
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 3002.41 ms   Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 3002.41 ms Phase: invoke Status: error Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
```

My Postgres connection string is currently setup as the following:

```
host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=us-east-2-bundle.pem password=%s
```

I downloaded the us-east-2 certs from here:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.RegionCertificates
```

If I update my Postgres connection string to the following:

```
host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable password=%s
```

Then the the error in the logs changes to:

```
failed to connect to `host=myHOST user=postgres database=api`: server error (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.2.0.12", user "postgres", database "api", no encryption (SQLSTATE 28000))
```

This is what prompted me to update my Postgres connection string to include SSL verification. Given that the error is related to SSL when using `sslmode=disable`, this tells me it is not an IAM/Security Group/Permissions issue.

My RDS instance is using `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1` as its CA. Is there something I am missing to connect to my RDS instance from my Lambda with SSL?

*UPDATE*

Here is the requested code that contains how the connection to the DB is established:

```
func OpenDB(DbUser, DbPassword, DbPort, DbHost, DbName string) (*gorm.DB, error) {
    DBURL := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=us-east-2-bundle.pem password=%s", DbHost, DbPort, DbUser, DbName, DbPassword)

    return gorm.Open(postgres.Open(DBURL), &gorm.Config{})
}
```

It just makes use of the gORM postgres utility.

*UPDATE 2*

The `Runtime.Unknown` is caused by `INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10007.03 ms Phase: init Status: timeout`

I have tried setting the Lambda timeout to both 10 and 30 seconds.

I have also tried using the global-bundle.pem (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.CertificatesAllRegions) but the issue remains.

The code works when connecting to a locally running postgres instance, but I cannot test running the code locally against the RDS instance as it is in a VPC that does not have access to the internet.

Comment: Please show us your code. I'd be especially interested to see how `sslrootcert=us-east-2-bundle.pem` is being interpreted by your Lambda function.

Comment: Updated to include the requested code.

Comment: You don't mention what library (or language) you are using, but it is unlikely to know how to interpret `sslrootcert=us-east-2-bundle.pem`. Presumably, that is a filename but without a full path to the file, it probably isn't being found (or possibly isn't even being sought). I know it is okay syntax for the `psql` command-line, but that doesn't mean other libraries will implement it the same way. Try to find some code examples for that library that show `sslmode` being used and copy what they do.

Comment: I understand that the issue could be in GORM, or the code. But my question was around the AWS side of things, does anything else need to be setup on the AWS side to make authentication with RDS work from _any_ library/language. For example, some material refers to using different Option groups, is that something that is required? In regards to the PEM file, as this is a Lambda the PEM file is bundled into the ZIP file, so it is available at the default file path.

Comment: What is the error message when you DO try to use SSL?

Comment: It is in the original post.
```
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 3002.41 ms   Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 3002.41 ms Phase: invoke Status: error Error Type: Runtime.Unknown
```

Comment: Ah! That is saying that your function timed-out after 3 seconds. It most probably timed-out while attempting to connect to the database (but you could add some debugging statements to confirm this). Have you tried increasing the Lambda function's timeout? If you run your code locally, does it work?

Comment: Updated the question with the requested info